# Bitnami Moodle container does not connec to maria db

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, bitnami, azure-web-app-for-containers

In Azure "Web App for Containers" service I have the following docker-compose.yml file. Based on this: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-moodle/blob/master/3/debian-11/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:3
    environment:
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=Moodle v3 Test 1
      - MOODLE_USERNAME=foobar_user
      - MOODLE_PASSWORD=foobar1111
    volumes:
      - 'moodle_data:/bitnami/moodle'
      - 'moodledata_data:/bitnami/moodledata'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  moodle_data:
    driver: local
  moodledata_data:
    driver: local
```

When I start the service and and inspect the logs I see that the Moodle image is having a hard time accessing the mariadb image. Below is the full dump of the logs. Sorry for the length of this, but I am hoping that someone will be able to recognize a detail within this that may shed light on what is happening.

```
2022-08-03T21:00:16.439123068Z 2022-08-03 21:00:16 93 [Warning] Aborted connection 93 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:17.521479030Z 2022-08-03 21:00:17 94 [Warning] Aborted connection 94 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:18.581491876Z 2022-08-03 21:00:18 95 [Warning] Aborted connection 95 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:19.663574884Z 2022-08-03 21:00:19 96 [Warning] Aborted connection 96 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:20.707537733Z 2022-08-03 21:00:20 97 [Warning] Aborted connection 97 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:21.852634128Z 2022-08-03 21:00:21 98 [Warning] Aborted connection 98 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:22.928465477Z 2022-08-03 21:00:22 99 [Warning] Aborted connection 99 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:24.016558849Z 2022-08-03 21:00:23 100 [Warning] Aborted connection 100 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:25.470200759Z 2022-08-03 21:00:25 101 [Warning] Aborted connection 101 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:26.539066866Z 2022-08-03 21:00:26 102 [Warning] Aborted connection 102 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:27.555060538Z 2022-08-03 21:00:27 103 [Warning] Aborted connection 103 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:28.738963126Z 2022-08-03 21:00:28 104 [Warning] Aborted connection 104 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:30.332358501Z 2022-08-03 21:00:30 105 [Warning] Aborted connection 105 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:31.727591512Z 2022-08-03 21:00:31 106 [Warning] Aborted connection 106 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:33.470704078Z 2022-08-03 21:00:33 107 [Warning] Aborted connection 107 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:34.448130283Z 2022-08-03 21:00:34 108 [Warning] Aborted connection 108 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:35.461661803Z 2022-08-03 21:00:35 109 [Warning] Aborted connection 109 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:36.487652089Z 2022-08-03 21:00:36 110 [Warning] Aborted connection 110 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:37.517595106Z 2022-08-03 21:00:37 111 [Warning] Aborted connection 111 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:38.584427503Z 2022-08-03 21:00:38 112 [Warning] Aborted connection 112 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:39.610105028Z 2022-08-03 21:00:39 113 [Warning] Aborted connection 113 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:40.646019026Z 2022-08-03 21:00:40 114 [Warning] Aborted connection 114 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:41.644863168Z 2022-08-03 21:00:41 115 [Warning] Aborted connection 115 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:42.660142054Z 2022-08-03 21:00:42 116 [Warning] Aborted connection 116 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:43.711739776Z 2022-08-03 21:00:43 117 [Warning] Aborted connection 117 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:44.709783446Z 2022-08-03 21:00:44 118 [Warning] Aborted connection 118 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:45.732673758Z 2022-08-03 21:00:45 119 [Warning] Aborted connection 119 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:46.762388450Z 2022-08-03 21:00:46 120 [Warning] Aborted connection 120 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:47.758876853Z 2022-08-03 21:00:47 121 [Warning] Aborted connection 121 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:48.776094540Z 2022-08-03 21:00:48 122 [Warning] Aborted connection 122 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:50.340782878Z 2022-08-03 21:00:50 123 [Warning] Aborted connection 123 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:55.361470046Z 2022-08-03 21:00:55 124 [Warning] Aborted connection 124 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:56.388063845Z 2022-08-03 21:00:56 125 [Warning] Aborted connection 125 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:57.421708836Z 2022-08-03 21:00:57 126 [Warning] Aborted connection 126 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:58.437290366Z 2022-08-03 21:00:58 127 [Warning] Aborted connection 127 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:00:59.447538290Z 2022-08-03 21:00:59 128 [Warning] Aborted connection 128 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:01:00.493517915Z 2022-08-03 21:01:00 129 [Warning] Aborted connection 129 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
2022-08-03T21:01:01.505069338Z 2022-08-03 21:01:01 130 [Warning] Aborted connection 130 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.16.24.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

2022-08-03T21:01:06.794Z INFO - Container logs from moodlev3-docker-1_moodle_0_8777f90c = 2022-08-03T20:57:20.591495328Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.59 [0m
2022-08-03T20:57:20.609727111Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.60 [0m[1mWelcome to the Bitnami moodle container[0m
2022-08-03T20:57:20.620203620Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.61 [0mSubscribe to project updates by watching [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers[0m
2022-08-03T20:57:20.647346277Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.64 [0mSubmit issues and feature requests at [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues[0m
2022-08-03T20:57:20.666697957Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.66 [0m
2022-08-03T20:57:20.686110642Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.68 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting Moodle setup **
2022-08-03T20:57:20.872220400Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:20.85 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Validating settings in APACHE_* environment variables
2022-08-03T20:57:21.326406628Z realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
2022-08-03T20:57:21.355210529Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:21.33 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
2022-08-03T20:57:21.366166280Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:21.36 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Configuring ServerTokens Prod on file /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf
2022-08-03T20:57:21.868867817Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:21.86 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring PHP options
2022-08-03T20:57:21.887165406Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:21.88 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
2022-08-03T20:57:22.109567044Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:22.10 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
2022-08-03T20:57:22.200697195Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:22.19 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars
2022-08-03T20:57:22.390634457Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:22.38 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Validating settings in MOODLE_* environment variables...
2022-08-03T20:57:22.762741913Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:22.76 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Ensuring Moodle directories exist
2022-08-03T20:57:23.111049117Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:23.11 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Trying to connect to the database server
2022-08-03T20:57:23.139873300Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:23.13 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:23.148274123Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:23.618638938Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:28.736342289Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:28.73 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:28.737759302Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:28.776248773Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:33.807767194Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:33.80 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:33.845294560Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:33.871246387Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:38.914237527Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:38.91 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:38.915290320Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:38.943604825Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:43.976763752Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:43.97 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:43.977475015Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:44.006532384Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:49.156310564Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:49.14 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:49.157092733Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:49.265267210Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:54.328419472Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:54.32 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:54.329748383Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:54.376230493Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:57:59.404119697Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:57:59.40 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:57:59.406432892Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:57:59.441740060Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:04.474194391Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:04.47 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:04.474852346Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:04.502372933Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:09.526378548Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:09.52 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:09.527644953Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:09.564180782Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:14.595786711Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:14.59 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:14.596793094Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:14.626229833Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:19.693104850Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:19.69 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:19.693972122Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:19.751356195Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:24.778342010Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:24.77 [0m[38;5;1mERROR[0m ==> Could not connect to the database
2022-08-03T20:58:32.265779242Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.25 [0m
2022-08-03T20:58:32.265811645Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.26 [0m[1mWelcome to the Bitnami moodle container[0m
2022-08-03T20:58:32.362755163Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.27 [0mSubscribe to project updates by watching [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers[0m
2022-08-03T20:58:32.362791267Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.28 [0mSubmit issues and feature requests at [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues[0m
2022-08-03T20:58:32.362797567Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.29 [0m
2022-08-03T20:58:32.362802167Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.30 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> ** Starting Moodle setup **
2022-08-03T20:58:32.381449467Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.37 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Validating settings in APACHE_* environment variables
2022-08-03T20:58:32.585382466Z realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
2022-08-03T20:58:32.602522037Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.60 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
2022-08-03T20:58:32.613771302Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.61 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Configuring ServerTokens Prod on file /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf
2022-08-03T20:58:32.839203521Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.83 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Configuring PHP options
2022-08-03T20:58:32.858137102Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:32.85 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
2022-08-03T20:58:33.084887121Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.08 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
2022-08-03T20:58:33.133969776Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.13 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars
2022-08-03T20:58:33.402267480Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.39 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Validating settings in MOODLE_* environment variables...
2022-08-03T20:58:33.698535666Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.69 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Ensuring Moodle directories exist
2022-08-03T20:58:33.951847841Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.95 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Trying to connect to the database server
2022-08-03T20:58:33.988771717Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:33.98 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:33.996028561Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:34.185064474Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:39.220559645Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:39.21 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:39.228124917Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:39.259267085Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:44.291723055Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:44.28 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:44.293894037Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:44.322373229Z ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'mariadb' (115)
2022-08-03T20:58:49.353190272Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:49.35 [0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Executing SQL command:
2022-08-03T20:58:49.353798324Z SELECT 1
2022-08-03T20:58:49.408754680Z 1
2022-08-03T20:58:49.421740880Z [38;5;6mmoodle [38;5;5m20:58:49.42 [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Running Moodle install script
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422292640Z .-..-.
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422335744Z _____ | || |
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422343245Z /____/-.---_ .---. .---. .-.| || | .---.
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422348945Z | | _ _ |/ _ \/ _ \/ _ || |/ __ \
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422354446Z * | | | | | || |_| || |_| || |_| || || |___/
2022-08-03T20:58:51.422359746Z |_| |_| |_|\_____/\_____/\_____||_|\_____)
2022-08-03T20:58:51.425938649Z
2022-08-03T20:58:51.425988453Z Moodle 3.11.8 (Build: 20220711) command line installation program
2022-08-03T20:58:52.928214968Z -->System

2022-08-03T21:01:14.435Z INFO - Stopping site moodlev3-docker-1 because it failed during startup.
```

Any thoughts as to why this is failing during startup? I expect the issue is credentials as supplied through the environment variables but this same configuration has worked locally and on AWS.

Comment: Try removing "driver: local" and add the mariadb listening port

Comment: Do you have more specific directions on how to add a listening port. Where would I add this? When I remove driver: local should I keep the volumes listed? So that it looks like   `mariadb_data: \n moodle_data: \n moodledata_data:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your Compose file with these modifications: remove **driver: local** from each volume and set the port that the mariadb service is listening on.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    ports:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:3
    environment:
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=foobar1111
      - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=Moodle v3 Test 1
      - MOODLE_USERNAME=foobar_user
      - MOODLE_PASSWORD=foobar1111
    volumes:
      - 'moodle_data:/bitnami/moodle'
      - 'moodledata_data:/bitnami/moodledata'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
  moodle_data:
  moodledata_data:
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now getting slightly different error in logs: `driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ...mariadb`

Comment: Hummm, port issue. Try removing the port from the mariadb service

Comment: Hi so I am going to accept this answer because it got farther than I was. I can say now that it still doesn't succeed. But according to the logs it looks like the connection to the DB is fine. (at a certain point it says `SELECT 1` and the next line is `1` I take this to mean that the connection worked) But it appears that it fails during the automated application (moodle) install script. https://pastebin.com/aUMHjBXx Any thoughts?

Comment: If you look at the docker run commands, you'll see that Azure maps port 8080 to the mariadb container an none for the moodle one. Edit your compose file adding port "3306" to mariadb and port "80:80" to the moodle container, assuming that it listens on port 80.

Comment: So. Interesting thing happening now. After these latest changes is stopped printing verbose logs. And I see the message in the log monitor `Logging is not enabled for this container.` along side some sort of terse startup messages.

Comment: You need to enable the application logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer

Comment: Ok I guess that after a period of like 20 or 30 minutes. The logs do eventually make it to the Deployment Center log viewer page. This time it looks like the moodle install script completes entirely and then the container breaks down. https://pastebin.com/FwUZq1RF

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the debug mode, I could realize that in the azure container the DB was lost, so I had to uncomment the line

```
 - MOODLE_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP=yes
```

load a backup and then everything worked